# Python - Conditional expression

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou aprendendo Python e em meus estudos me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```
>>> responses = ['Y', 'Yes', 'No', 'no', '', 'Yep']
>>> responses = [x[0].lower() if x else 'n' for x in responses]
>>> responses
['y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y']
```

Não consigo entender, neste caso o que faz o **x** ser **True** ou **False**?

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja outra versão sem o listcomps:

```
responses = ['Y', 'Yes', 'No', 'no', '', 'Yep']
n=0
for x in responses:
    n+=1
    if x:
        print(x,n)
    else:    
        print ('o unico elemento em que x é false', n)

Y 1
Yes 2
No 3
no 4
o unico elemento em que x é false 5
Yep 6
```

Ou seja, x é false somente no elemento em que a string é nula.

Comment: Putz, simples! Eu não me atentei no True, fiquei tentando entender o n das outras. Obrigado Sidon.